# C++ global variable lifespan

Tags: c++, global

I have a global variable which is an instance of a class. This class created an image in its constructor (directX).

The problem is that I am getting an access violation at runtime but the code compiles. I think the problem is that the class constructor is being called before the initialisation done in the winmain function.

so what I want to know is

1. has anyone encountered this problem and knows of a solution.
2. What is the lifespan of a global, i know variables declared in a function are lost after it returns and that the compiler looks through the code the see if everything matches which is why we have to prototype functions but where do global's come into the equation.

Comment: afaik globals should last the entirety of the lifespan of your program, but without code, that's hard to say if that's the case with you.

Comment: Is your global variable in a DLL?

Comment: @paperjam the winmain calls a game run function in a loop and the code is in there, came from a book and designed to separate initialisation and game code but means things have to be global as they get destroyed between call of the game run function. open to a better setup if you have an idea

Comment: Global variables **are** initialized before the first statement of main. Their lifetime is from their construction until the end of the program. They are then destructed in the reverse order of their construction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to look at something like the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) if you really want to have one instance of a global, that can be initialized after the initialisation is done (essentially, the image would be constructed the first time you referenced it after which you'd use the pre-constructed version).

Globals are constructed (in undefined order), before your winmain is called.  They stay there until your program exits (at which point I believe the destructors are called in an undefined order)..

Another (possibly simpler) alternative you could use would be to change your global from an instance of the class to a pointer to it...  then you'd have something like:

```
// global...
MyGlobalClass *bigGlobalImageHolder;

// Winmain
// Perform directX setup (don't know what that is)
// Create the image class
bigGlobalImageHolder = new MyGlobalClass();


// do the rest of your stuff...  I'm guessing enter some kind of event loop

// clean up your global
delete bigGlobalImageHolder;
// exit your winmain (and application)
```

Then everywhere you're currently referencing your global, you could reference it via a pointer instead..

```
 // so
 bigGlobalImageHolder.GetImage();
 // becomes
 bigGlobalImageHolder->GetImage();
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, destructors are called in the same order that constructors are called, but reverse. It is the constructors that are called in an undefined order. And even then, if two globals are defined in the same file, first defined will be also initialized first, and thus destroyed last.

Comment: Singletons are only applicable in the very rare situation when you genuinely need to restrict a class to a single instance, which doesn't sound like the case here - there's just a requirement for a globally-accessible object. In C++, singletons have plenty of issues of their own (in particular, thread-safe creation and control of destruction order) which make them tricky to implement correctly. I would advise against singletons, but +1 for your suggestion of creating the object in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are experiencing the "static initialization order fiasco".

Check this [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14) and the following faqs.

As already mentioned above, you'll probably want to implement one or another kind of [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton).

Answer (score 0):

1. I have faced this problem; Whatever code is used in that `class constructor` should be initialized before the `class constructor` starts. Suppose if the other variables are also globals then their constructor should be called first. Though constructors for `global` variables are called in undefined way, only small work around you can use is, define the dependent global variables in same files in order from least dependent to most dependent.
2. Global lifespan is equal to your program lifespan

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of global statical data is for the lifetime of the application. However, on normal termination, destructors *will* run.

The problem with this is that the order in which initialization/destruction take place is not always deterministic, and certainly isn't portable (i.e. depends on platform and e.g. runtime linkers).

The situation is worst with shared object (dynamic linking). Some platforms allow to use linker flags to specify 'priorities' for shared objects (so that the static initialization order can be influenced); Other platforms (e.g. AIX gcc, HP/UX) require special compiler attributes to mark static procedures as 'dll initialization routines'.

---

In short: do not depend on statical data, except through accessor functions. An accessor function might look like this:

```
 static int _myinternalvar = 3;
 static int GetMyInternalVar()
 {
      return _myinternalvar;
 }
```

this way, you *will* know for sure that the static was initialized before the function is executed. It the accessor is the only function that can access the data, you can declare the static within it's scope (adding encapsulation).